# Why does the signal primitive of a counting semaphore check if s<=0 instead of s<0?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, semaphore

I have a question about the signal primitive of a counting semaphore. In my textbook, the counting semaphore is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct{
    int value;
    struct process *L;
} semaphore;

void wait(semaphore S) { 
    S.value--;
    if(S.value<0){
        add this process to S.L;
        block(S.L);
    }
}

void signal(semaphore S) { 
    S.value++;
    if (S.value<=0) { // My question is why it uses <= instead of <
        remove a process P from S.L; 
        wakeup(P);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that **`s`** represents the number of resources. When **`s==0`**, it means that there are no free resources available, but it does not mean that there are processes requesting the resource. I think using **`s<0`** would be more appropriate because it means that there are no free resources and there are processes blocked due to requesting the resource.

Can anyone explain why the signal primitive checks if s<=0 instead of s<0? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to my question. I didn’t take into account that the `signal` function increments the value of `S.value` before checking the `if` condition. So if there is at least one process that needs the resource, the value of `S.value` will be less than or equal to 0.